# How do I create a generics class with another generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I'm not very good with generics or erasure types but I have the following classes:

```
AbstractEventBuffer<BufferedEvent<T>>
```

and

```
BufferedEvent<T>
```

I have concrete implementations of these classes I'm working with, but the `AbstractEventBuffer` that takes a `BufferedEvent` will not let me use `T` how I have it.

I'm trying to keep these very generic to minimize replication of code later on.

Why can I not create my `AbstractEventBuffer` class like..

```
public abstract class AbstractEventBuffer<BufferedEvent<T>>
```

Comment: Are you trying to declare a class or create an instance?  What error are you getting when you try?

Comment: can you post a snippet please and show whats not working (where the compile error is)

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you declare a class, you declare type parameters (which are a kind of type variables), which of course can't have parameters of their own. What do you really want to do?

Answer (score 3):

maybe you think about such declaration (I think this is it):

```
public abstract class AbstractEventBuffer<E extends BufferedEvent<?>>
```

or:

```
public abstract class AbstractEventBuffer<T, E extends BufferedEvent<T>>
```

or

```
public abstract class AbstractEventBuffer<E extends BufferedEvent<? extends Object>>
```

or such:

```
public abstract class AbstractEventBuffer<BufferedEvent> {
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you heard the crowd:

> Make the class concrete.

Once concrete you can make it be a `generic` class that only accepts `Event` (of any type) or subclasses of `Event` as it's type by doing:

```
public class Buffer<T extends Event<?>> {
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: sorry for the lack of info, i do have a class that extends my abstract class that i'm trying to do this with.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done java in a while (moved on to C#) but if I remember clearly something like this is possible:

```
public abstract class Buffer<T extends Event<I>>
```

And of course you first need to extend this abstract class buffer because you can't instantiate a abstract class.

Comment: it is not compiling, look at similar sample in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your question like you may also want to try something like:

```
public class EventBuffer<T> extends Buffer<Event<T>> {
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit confusing, following code is legal and perhaps doing what you want. The **event should probably keep its type parameter for itself** but if you insist on using it the first example from zacheusz with two type params is the right way. Don't overdo it :)

```
class BufferedEvent<T>{}

abstract class AbstractEventBuffer<E extends BufferedEvent>{}

class EventBuffer<E extends BufferedEvent> extends AbstractEventBuffer
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
          EventBuffer<BufferedEvent> buffer = new EventBuffer<BufferedEvent>();
    }
}
```